# Random Quote Machine - Cant tweet quote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to tweet a quote that I randomly generated using APIs, but my code isn't working. Here is my code, I added comments trying to make it look clearer. I am a novice in coding so it probably has a terrible sintax. 
I manage to get my quote by clicking on the "Get another quote" button, but when i want to tweet my quote, clicking on the "Tweet quote" button it wont work and i get the "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at pen.js:10" error. 
I dont know what i am doing wrong.
(This is a task for FreeCodeCamp). Thanks to everyone who will answer!

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<h2 class="title">Random Quote Generator</h2>
<h4 class="subtitle">A project for the FreeCodeCamp challenge</h4>

<div class="container-box">
<div class="container-quote">
<p class="quote" id ="quote"></p>

<div class="container-author" id="author">
  <p></p>
</div> <!--closing div for container author-->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <button id="tweetQuote" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=data.quoteText">Tweet this quote!</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
  <button id="newQuote">Get another quote</button>
  </div>

</div> <!--row-->


</div> <!--closing div for container quote-->


</div> <!--closing div for container-->
```

And now the javascript

```
//setting html elements to variables

var $newQuote = $('#newQuote');
var $quote = $('#quote');
var $tweetQuote = $('#tweetQuote');

//execute function by clicking on button

$newQuote.click(getQuote);
$tweetQuote.click(tweetIt);

var text = data.quoteText;
var author = data.quoteAuthor;

//when getQuote is called call the APIs and get the quote by executing 
getQuoteFromAPI

function getQuote() {
$quote.empty();
getQuoteFromAPI();
};

function getQuoteFromAPI() {

var url='https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/? 
method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?';

//when the APIs are completely called execute the parseQuote function
$.getJSON(url).done(parseQuote);

 //log the datas on the console and transform them into real html elements
function parseQuote (response) {
console.log(response);
document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = response.quoteText;

document.getElementById('author').innerHTML = response.quoteAuthor;
};
};

function tweetIt() {

var url='https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/? 
method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?';

$('#tweetQuote').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + text + '-' + author);

};
```

Comment: As the error suggests, your not defining data anywhere `var text = data.quoteText;
var author = data.quoteAuthor;`

Comment: As Lawrence pointed out, data is undefined in the line "text = data.quoteText" ... but also, text and author are only set once; parseQuote is not reassigning them, so you will always tweet the first thing assigned to them.

Comment: You should initially define them empty, then in the parseQuote function define them with the values of the response, then it will be available when tweetIt is fired.

Comment: sidenote, avoid using `$` in your variable names, not required makes it look ugly, your not coding PHP its javascript ;p

Comment: Ok thank you, i understood that data is not defined and thats why i get my first error. So what should i do? Using "response.quoteText/Author" instead of data.quoteText/Author? Will that work? 
And i didn't understant what you suggested about parseQuote: how do i define Text and Author inside parseQuote?
And the last thing: should i put the 'tweetIt" function inside the getQuoteFromApi function or outside? Again thanks for your help.

Comment: And you are right, $ is not required, i won't use that anymore :)